# How to change the number of target instances in an Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I've created an Azure VMSS and used a target instance count of 1 during my testing.  Now that I'm ready to go live for my customer, I really need to change the target instance count to at least 2 for HA reasons.  Is there a way to do this via Azure CLI or other means without having to rebuild everything?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this via Azure CLI or other means without having
>   to rebuild everything?

Yes, we can use [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) to configure and update the autoscale setting for a scale set. Azure Resource Explorer is an easy way to manage Azure resources via Resource Manager templates. Here are my steps:
1. login [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/).
2. switch Read Only to **Read/Write**.
[image]
3. select subscription and resource group, find the vmss and autoscalesettings, then **edit** it.
[image]
4. After edit is complete, select **PUT**.
[image]
5. Then we can find the result from Azure protal.
[image]

More information about configure and update the autoscale setting for a scale set, refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-advanced-autoscale-virtual-machine-scale-sets).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Yes! I somehow have never come across this in the documentation.  Thank you!

Comment: Note, using the Azure portal, Azure CLI, or Azure PowerShell is the easiest way to change the capacity of a scale set.

Comment: @sendmarsh OK, I will check it later, at that time, Azure does not support that, maybe Azure update it now. I will update it later, thank you for your advice:)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the capacity of a VM Scale set in the following ways:

1. Use the Azure portal - Click on your VM scale set and then select the Scaling blade. Use the slider bar.
2. Use the CLI 2.0 az vmss scale command.
3. Using Azure PowerShell 5.0.0 or later use this command:

   Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName myrg -VMScaleSetName myvmss -SkuCapacity 3